# How To Optimise a MySQL Query with Order and Limit and Use of MySQL Function

Tags: mysql

The following query takes pretty long (few seconds) to execute:

```
select * from Geo_1M_Landl order by abs(`fieldvalue` - $lat) limit 10
```

where $lat is some number.

The table has about 3 million rows.

Is there any way to optimise it / make it faster? I tried adding an index to `fieldvalue` but it's a longtext type and returning an #1170 error. What if I do not know what the maximum length of the column is?

Comment: If it's a number why are you storing it as text?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL cannot use an index to `order by` a derived value, so it has to calculate `abs(fieldvalue - $lat)` for all your 3 million rows, then sort them all, and only then know which of those are the first 10.

(Auto-)casting your string value to a number value counts as calculation too: since `8`, `08`, `000008.00000` all represent the same number, but are completely different strings (stored at different places in an index), the index would be useless to find rows with a value that, read as a number, equals 8, so MySQL will just go through every row and cast the value to a number and then do something with this.

So to be able to use an index, you first need to change your column to a number type (probably decimal or float). If you do this, make sure you check if all your values are valid numbers, otherwise they might (depending on your server configuration) be transformed to some unexpected number. Especially check `''`, which most likely should become `null` and not `0`.

Then you need to get rid of the need to order all your rows by a calculated value. You can do this by preselecting potential rows and then only do the (more expensive) ordering on that smaller subset:

```
select * from     
  ((select * from Geo_1M_Landl 
    where `fieldvalue` >= $lat order by `fieldvalue` limit 10)
    union all
   (select * from Geo_1M_Landl 
    where `fieldvalue` < $lat order by `fieldvalue` desc limit 10)
  ) subquery
order by abs(`fieldvalue` - $lat) limit 10;
```

This will lookup the 10 rows below and above your `$lat` value (which will certainly contain the 10 rows you want), now being able to use the index (on the *number* value), and then only need to sort those (up to) 20 rows by your expression. This will obviously get less effective if your limit (significantly) increases.